# Download.file function in R and manual download

Tags: javascript, html, r, download, web-scraping

When I right click on a web page, and download the page with Chrome, I usually have a html file, and a folder with diverse files (images, js, css etc.)

When I use the R function download.file to do this, I only have a html file, and it has less elements than the html file that I manually downlaoded.

I try to use different options in the download.file function, in vain.

Is it possible to download the web page with R to get the same file that we can download manually ?

Here is the example:
url="http://www.elysee.fr/declarations"

```
download.file(url,"page_decla.html",mode="a",extra = getOption("download.file.extra"),
              method="auto")
```

Comment: Web pages are not generally a single file, but are composed of several,  The html page contains links to the various images, style sheets etc.  To download everything, one may need to parse out the base html file to identify the various links and then download those files separately.  May not be easy but doable.  I would recommend the rvest package for scrapping the html page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Dave2e, but with rvest, you will have the same problem. You will see the source code, just like the file you download with the download.file function.

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate the "manual download", which will execute all js requests, I found the solution: rselenium. It will in fact remote control the browser. Then what you "see" everything as in your manually downloaded file.